# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=13, address = 0x0)

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Have a program which compiles, but then quits, returning the above error message.

Here is the 0 objc_msgSend log; have commented out the line the error message appears on:

```
libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend:
0x7fff8c9b7e80:  testq  %rdi, %rdi
0x7fff8c9b7e83:  je     0x00007fff8c9b7eb0       ; objc_msgSend + 48
0x7fff8c9b7e85:  testb  $1, %dil
0x7fff8c9b7e89:  jne    0x00007fff8c9b7ec7       ; objc_msgSend + 71
0x7fff8c9b7e8c:  movq   (%rdi), %r11
0x7fff8c9b7e8f:  pushq  %rax
0x7fff8c9b7e90:  movq   16(%r11), %r10
0x7fff8c9b7e94:  movl   %esi, %eax
0x7fff8c9b7e96:  andl   (%r10), %eax           // error message arrow appears on this line
0x7fff8c9b7e99:  movq   16(%r10,%rax,8), %r11
0x7fff8c9b7e9e:  incl   %eax
0x7fff8c9b7ea0:  testq  %r11, %r11
0x7fff8c9b7ea3:  je     0x00007fff8c9b7edb       ; objc_msgSend + 91
0x7fff8c9b7ea5:  cmpq   (%r11), %rsi
0x7fff8c9b7ea8:  jne    0x00007fff8c9b7e96       ; objc_msgSend + 22
0x7fff8c9b7eaa:  popq   %rax

// Rest left out; no error messages
```

main.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Budget.h"

#import "Transaction.h"
#import "CashTransaction.h"
#import "CreditCardTransaction.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    Budget *europeBudget = [Budget new];
    [europeBudget createBudget:1000.00 withExchangeRate:1.2500];

    Budget *englandBudget = [Budget new];
    [englandBudget createBudget:2000.00 withExchangeRate:1.5000];


    NSMutableArray *transactions = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:10];
    Transaction *aTransaction;
    for (int n=1; n < 2; n++) {

        [aTransaction createTransaction:n * 100 forBudget:europeBudget];
        [transactions addObject:aTransaction];
        aTransaction = [CashTransaction new];
        [aTransaction createTransaction:n * 100 forBudget:englandBudget];
        [transactions addObject:aTransaction];
    }

    int n = 1;
    while (n < 4) {

        [aTransaction createTransaction:n * 100 forBudget:europeBudget];
        [transactions addObject:aTransaction];
        aTransaction = [CreditCardTransaction new];
        [aTransaction createTransaction:n * 100 forBudget:englandBudget];
        [transactions addObject:aTransaction];
        n++;
    }


        for (Transaction * aTransaction in transactions) {
            [aTransaction spend];
    }


            return 0;
}
```

Transaction.h

## import

@class Budget;

```
@interface Transaction : NSObject
{
    Budget *budget;
    double amount;
}

- (void) createTransaction:(double)theAmount forBudget:(Budget*) aBudget;
- (void) spend;
- (void)trackSpending: (double) theAmount;

@end
```

Transaction.m

```
#import "Transaction.h"
#import "Budget.h"

@implementation Transaction

- (void) createTransaction:(double)theAmount forBudget:(Budget*) aBudget
{
    budget = aBudget;
    amount = theAmount;
}

- (void) spend
{
    // Fill in the method in subclasses
}

-(void)trackSpending: (double) theAmount
{
    NSLog(@"You are about to spend another %.2f", theAmount);
}
@end
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but 0x0 is hex for NULL.  I think you're messaging a null object.

Comment: Thought it might be in the NSMutableArray object but couldn't find it. Have added the main.m file for your perusal.

Comment: Sending a message to a nil object is totally fine. It returns zero, which the compiler casts to the return type of the function. (That's a problem if your return type is, say, NSRect, but newer versions of the SDK handle that correctly, as I recall.) A crash in objc_messageSend usually means you're sending a message to a freed object.

Answer (score 6):

I landed on this issue while I was looking for a solution to another problem around SIGSEGV.

Although it is a bit late response, I would like to answer this question for the sake of documentation and completeness.

The problems arises because you are sending messages to an object without instantiating one.

```
Transaction *aTransaction;
for (int n=1; n < 2; n++) {

    [aTransaction createTransaction:n * 100 forBudget:europeBudget];
```

and create method was defined as:

```
- (void) createTransaction:(double)theAmount forBudget:(Budget*) aBudget;
```

I would write these methods as follows.

First of all, createTransaction sounds like a factory method to me. So, I would make it a class method, like:

```
+(Transaction *) createTransactionWithAmount:(double) theAmount forBudget: (Budget *) aBudget;
```

Then I would use that factory method like below:

```
for (int n=1; n < 2; n++) {
     Transaction *aTransaction = [Transaction createTransactionWithAmount: n*100 forBudget: europeBudget];
   // [aTransaction createTransaction:n * 100 forBudget:europeBudget];
    [transactions addObject:aTransaction];
```

That should fix 2 problems with the code:

1) You will always have an instance to send messages against defined as aTransaction var
2) You don't have to worry about adding this object into the collection as it won't be nil anymore.

Answer (score 2):

aTransaction isn't assigned a value when it's declared, so it starts out with a garbage value. The first time through the loop, you're sending a message to that garbage value: crash! Declaring the variable with a nil initial value will fix the problem:

```
Transaction *aTransaction = nil;
```

Comment: Question: The Transaction class has two instance variables: Budget and Amount. Why does it crash if the default ivars are populated in the enum function? I have added the Transaction.h, .m files for your review. Changed the code to "Transaction *aTransaction = nil;" but I got a crash. Got a thread 1: signal SIGABRT message on the [transactions addObject:aTransaction]; line

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "enum function". I don't see anything obviously wrong in the code if you're initializing aTransaction. Try turning on NSZombieEnabled (google for directions on that) and see what it says.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response; I just tried coding it again from scratch to see if I got the same error, and I did. For enum function, I meant the loops. Will see what I can find out by turning on NSZombie Enabled.

Comment: Have run it through Static Analyzer. Says that Reeiver in message expression is an uninitialized value [aTransaction createTransaction:n * 100 forBudget:europeBudget];  When I changed it to Transaction *aTransaction = nil; I got a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT on the [transactions addObject:aTransaction]; line.

Comment: D'oh! Sorry, I should have caught that. You can send a message to a nil object, but you can't add nil to an array--it throws an exception. If you want to keep the program flow like it is, you could protect the [transactions addObject:aTransaction] by putting a check for nil before it: if ( aTransaction != nil )

Comment: …though I wonder if that code is going to do what you want it to. It seems kind of convoluted, creating a new transaction object in the middle of the loop and rolling it back to the beginning.

Comment: @davehayden If this is ARC code (and I suspect it is because of the lack of release calls), then ALL objects are automatically initialized to `nil`. So in ARC, `Transaction *aTransaction;` is the same as `Transaction *aTransaction = nil;`